# Необрабатывается sql запрос

Tags: php, mysqli

У меня есть sql запрос,но он не обрабатывается, посмотрите пожалуйста и подскажите в чём ошибка

```
  $currentTime = (int)date('H');
  $currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
  $visible = 1;

for($i = 1; $i < 15; $i++){

  $time_set1 = find_all_time_f($i);
  $arrayOfFotball1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($time_set1);
  $time_count1 = mysqli_num_rows($time_set1);

  $time_f = $arrayOfFotball1['time'];
  $rdate_f = $arrayOfFotball1['rdate'];



  if(strtotime($currentdate) > $rdate_f)  //HERE we should check Date if date < then  change visibility
  {
  //2.Perfor database querys
    //exit("Error");
    $query  = "UPDATE sport_football SET ";
    $query .= "visible = {$visible} "; 
    $query .= "WHERE time = {$currentdate} ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  }else if($currentTime > $time_f){
    $query  = "UPDATE sport_football SET ";
    $query .= "visible = {$visible} "; 
    $query .= "WHERE time = {$currentdate} ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

  }//if statement

}//for loop

//check function for football
```

Comment: А у вас в базе точно в поле time лежит дата без времени. потому как иначе по равенству не найдет. И что то не вижу, чем у вас отличаются два update. может их надо в один `if` положить, дублировать код незачем. Ну и про дату вам ответили. Хотя его еще можно в кавычки заключить просто ...

Answer (score 1):

проблема тут

```
$query .= "WHERE time = {$currentdate} ";
```

В этот момент `$currentdate` содержит дату в формате 'XXXX-XX-XX', а это "текст"

надо вот так

```
$query .= "WHERE time = ".strtotime($currentdate);
```

Comment: интресено... а за что минус? что не так?

Comment: mysql в принципе поймет дату строкой, если она будет в кавычках. так что можно и `time='{$currentdate}'`. У нас тут минусатор на sql похоже завелся, за последние несколько дней у меня несколько минусов на нормальных ответах по теме ...

Comment: @Mike молодые люди, вы себе невероятно льстите, считая свои попытки что-то сочинить на ходу "нормальными ответами".

Comment: @Ипатьев Тогда пишите в комментариях к ответу, в чем именно мы не правы, давая тот или иной ответ. SO призван обучать. А если ученику ставят двойку и пр этом не объясняют причин, позволяя дальше заблуждаться - это не обучение. И еще странно выглядит заминусованный единственный, _рабочий_, ответ на вопрос в отсутствии каких либо других ответов.